# Pyqt5 widget style similar to tkinter style

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a qwidgets one with raised/sunkin/groove/ridge relief similar to tkinter. I know how to do this in tkinter, but don't know the style sheet option in Pyqt5 for each one. Please find the tkinter option
Widget = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="FLAT", relief=raised ). Hope you can help to translate to Pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `QFrame`. you can set `QFrame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)`. But I couldn't find for a `QWidget` one.